# Meaning of "scribbling down a message and stuffing it into a bottle"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> When I sat down to write my account of the experience—*Liar's Poker*, it was called—it was in the spirit of a young man who thought he was getting out while the getting was good. **I was merely scribbling down a message and stuffing it into a bottle** for those who passed through these parts in the far distant future. Unless some insider got all of this down on paper, I figured, no future human would believe that it had happened.—*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

Can I ask what the sentence in bold would mean as to what author meant to do while writing '*Liar's poker*'?

Comment: Do you know the concept of a [message in a bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_in_a_bottle)?

Comment: No..? Does that mean sending message to whoever gets the message?

Comment: Yes, and probably to be found some time later.

Comment: But can I ask why it says no future human would believe what he had written in a book? Does it have to do with him stuffed it into a bottle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [message in a bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_in_a_bottle) is the idea of writing a message on a piece of paper, rolling it up and putting it in a bottle and throwing it into the sea.

The idea is someone, somewhere may one day find the message (washed up on a beach they're on, while they're out in a boat) and read it — as per the Wikipedia page linked above, some people have used them as part of scientific experiments, but the main association is someone writing down their thoughts in the hope that anyone else would read it:

> The lore surrounding messages in bottles has often been of a romantic or poetic nature.

So from your introduction, what was Michael Lewis' rationale for deciding to write *Liar's Poker*:

> I was merely scribbling down a message and stuffing it into a bottle for those who passed through these parts in the far distant future.

He just wanted to have "gotten out on paper" his insider story, a first-hand account, regardless of who read it in the future.

> But can I ask why it says no future human would believe what he had written in a book? Does it have to do with him stuffed it into a bottle?

He's not saying that no-one would believe his book, he's saying if it *hadn't* written the book and someone later said "I heard a rumour once that people shorted the housing market by doing X, Y, Z" the response would be "I don't believe it. That's an urban legend", because the story itself is so outlandish.

> Unless some insider [Lewis himself] got all of this down on paper, I figured, no future human would believe that it had happened.

---

**EDIT:** Just to add for clarity — when you say "does it have to do with him stuff[ing] it into a bottle? — he's not *literally* writing a book & putting it in a bottle. He's just using that expression as a metaphor.

Comment: So,  Lewis recognizes his own fervor because what he knows is uncommon knowledge that he feels he must free from his own consciousness and share, even surreptitiously? Or that he 'has wishful thinking' that his whole truth might come to light after he is no longer around and must face public scrutiny?

Comment: @GWarner Yes exactly. I've only see the film adaptation of _The Big Short_ so haven't read this in context, but my straight reading of the metaphor would be what you're describing. Whether it's a/b or some combination of both, IMO is left open to interpretation.

Comment: Oh, first, I didn't know "insider" would indicate as himself. Now I get what he have done. Also, I wondered if he used expression "scribble down" to emphasize the meaning of giving information to any random people?

Comment: @iceman yeah, I definitely think both "scribbling down" and "stuffing it in" are emphasising him doing it without too much thought about the finished article or what would come of it.